# How to migrate text format

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm figuring out how migrating works. When trying to migrate one of my nodes from a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8 site I can't figure out how to set the Text Format of a field. I found this solution below, when looking for an answer, but this doesn't work.

```
field_name:
      plugin: get
      source: field_name
      process:
        value: value
        format:
          plugin: default_value
          default_value: "basic_html"
```

I also tried something like

```
field_name:
          plugin: get
          source: field_name
field_name/format:
          plugin: default_value
          default_value: "basic_html"
```

Or

```
field_name/value:
          plugin: get
          source: field_name
field_name/format:
          plugin: default_value
          default_value: "basic_html"
```

But non of these work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried removing the quotes?

```
field_reference:
-
  plugin: sub_process
  source: field_reference
  process:
    value: value
    format:
      plugin: default_value
      default_value: basic_html
```

Comment: Hi, yes i tried with and without quotes. But the result is the same. The text format in the created node says: _select_ instead of _Basic HTML_.

Comment: What about using sub process like above? I'm still just getting to grips with migrations but this worked for me.

Comment: Ah yes, I got the plugin wrong. This should be `sub_process` instead of `get`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is more elegant to use a `sub_process` as @dibs proposed, you can also use a `get` process plugin

```
field_name/value:
  - plugin: get
    source: field_name/0/value
field_name/format:
  - plugin: default_value
    default_value: basic_html
```

Comment: Yep this is working for me too

Comment: To avoid `The value you selected is not a valid choice` for the text format, ensure the `uid` user assigned the entity (e.g. node) has permission to use the format.

Comment: The user can be set to `blocked` (e.g. purpose built migration user)