# I'm writing a node migration module but only the title gets migrated

Tags: nodes, migrations, 9

How can I get the body migrated as well? When I compared this with other working migrations, there didn't seem to be any differences in the code/anything wrong with mine. I also looked for alternative process plugins but "sub_processes" seems to be working for everyone else just fine.

```yml
id: edweb_gen
label: Generic - Node
migration_group: edweb_gen
migration_tags:
  - 'edweb_generic'

source:
  plugin: d7_node
  key: migrate
  node_type: generic

process:
  nid: tnid
  vid: vid
  title: title
  uid: node_uid
  status: status
  created: created
  body:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: body
    process:
      value: value
      summary: summary
      format:
        plugin: static_map
        bypass: true
        source: format
        # format - 'destination': source
        map:
          'plain_text': basic_html
          'basic_tags': basic_html
          'minimal_formatting': basic_html
          'filtered_html': basic_html
          'extended_tags': full_html
          'full_html': full_html
          'uoe_text_format': full_html

destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: generic_content
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How migrate rich text fields from outside Drupal without converting html tags to entities](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/309173/how-migrate-rich-text-fields-from-outside-drupal-without-converting-html-tags-to)

Comment: This does not really work for me either. I'm guessing that is because the person asking is migrating from a non-Drupal (csv) source and is using an additional module but thanks anyways!

Comment: Is source really "body"?